# how to prevent image from overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a png of a trashcan icon at the right top of it parent div:

```
<div id="image_part">//width: 700, height:500

    <img id="preview_pic" alt="" src=""> //this is where I load image
    <img style="float:right;cursor:pointer; margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;" title="delete this photo" src="img/trashcan1_icon.png" height="20" width="20">

    </div>
```

When I load an image, if the image size is smaller than its parent size(which is image_part), then the image should be at the center of the **div image_part**, and still have margin between the **div image_part** and the image and the trashcan is visible. However, if the image is big enough to occupy all the **parent div image_part without any margin or space**, then the trashcan icon becomes invisible. What I want is for the trashcan icon to be at the top of the image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should propably bind the size of the image to a maximum: Use max-height: 500px, max-width: 700px (Or slightly smaller values so you have a margin).

You also can use z-index on the elements - either give the preview_picture a negative value or the trashcan a positive one (bigger than 1).

Comment: I simply add preview_image z-index:-3, and the trashcan 1, it works perfectly. But why I use make the both their z-index positive, and even preview_image's z-index is smaller than the trashcan z-index, it dosen't work, and I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the html like so:

```
<div id="image_part">//width: 700, height:500

    <img style="float:right;cursor:pointer; margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px;" title="delete this photo" src="img/trashcan1_icon.png" height="20" width="20">

    <img id="preview_pic" alt="" src=""> //this is where I load image

</div>
```

Comment: if i use code like this, unless I make the preview_pic div's position relative, then the transhcan would be at the top of the image,then the image goes beyond its parent(image_part), if I make the preview_pic absolute, then the trashcan is still invisible

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done with just CSS. Just center the `#preview_pic` both vertically and horizontally then apply `max-width` and `max-height` so you can preserve the aspect ratio of the image, then `z-index` the trashcan higher that the image.

```
#image_part {
  width:700px;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid #666;
  position:relative;
}
#trashcan {
  z-index:3;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#preview_pic {
  z-index:2;
  max-height:500px;
  max-width:700px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vD2u8/

Comment: oh, same approach to @Kjeld Schmidt answer.